# Angularjs - multi lines in text area

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I have a `textarea` in my `html` for user to input some text. I can get it to save into `mysql` table field with `text` attribute using `php`. Before insert into `mysql`, I will `mysql_real_escape_string($data);`(for security reason). But when I retrieve it back out from database, I will get

```
{"bittext":"i 
love
mcD"}
```

With that I will get error:

> Error: JSON Parse error: Unterminated string
>   parse@[native code]

I am not sure how I can reformat it back so that I can parse it to `JSON`.

**Update:**

I found out that I did not add `json_encode($data)` function. Now I can turn

```
{"bittext":"i 
love
mcD"}
```

into

```
{"bittext":"i\nlove\nmcD"}
```

But I am having problem to convert `\n` to `\\n` using `$data = str_replace(array('\r\n', '\r', '\n'),'\\n', $data);`. For some reason `\\n` is not working. Is there other way to do this?

**Update2:**
After much of messing around with the code, I finally got it to work:

```
     $je = json_encode($rs,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
     $nl = array('\r\n', '\r', '\n');
     $je = str_replace($nl,'\\n', $je);
```

My initial issue is when I `log` it with `firephpcore`, I can only see `\n` even after `str_replace($nl,'\\n', $je)`. But as I do more test and found out it actually already work even though it did not display well in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for `mysql_real_escape_string()`;

> mysql_real_escape_string() calls MySQL's library function
>   mysql_real_escape_string, which prepends backslashes to the following
>   characters: \x00, \n, \r, \, ', " and \x1a.

Your insert statement will inculde the string '{"bittext":"i \\nlove \\nmcD"}' - notice we are escaping the escape character here, which is what `mysql_real_escape_string()` does.

Which will insert into your table the string '{"bittext":"i \nlove \nmcD"}' - this is what you should see if you do a select from the mysql client.

Somewhere, either pre-insert, or post-select your code is processing the value and changing '\n', to an actual newline byte, instead of leaving it as the string '\n'.

You could patch this by running;

```
$data = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\\n", $data);
```

However, I would recommend you track back through your code to see where in your pipeline escaped strings are getting converted to actuals.

Comment: Somehow I cannot do `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "\\n", $data)` because `"\\n"` can is not a string. I tried with random combination like `str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "///", $data)` and it work. Is there other ways to do this?

Comment: After much of testing, I realize that it actually works. Although it appear on console as `\n`, it actually works.